# What is WSO2 API Manager OSGI and how to disable it

Tags: wso2, osgi, wso2-api-manager

I installed api manager and i am having osgi errors in the logs. I did not configure anything related to this service so i kept the default configuration.

What is the need of this service? can it be disabled to remove the log errors?

Sample of the errors:

```
ERROR ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key 
[1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 ...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.common.APIMConfigUtil.getTokenIssuerMap(APIMConfigUtil.java:45) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.common_9.28.177.jar:?]

  ...
 [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 8c50caef-1085-4a4c-80dc-2f7c271b4019] 
 ERROR 17] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
 [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference 
 to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with 
 key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext 
 resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: How did you install the WSO2 API Manager ? Did you get this error in the fresh pack server startup?

Comment: i installed the free version from scratch.

Comment: In the fresh pack, usually, this kind of error does not occur. You don't need to stop any service to make it work. What is your OS, and where did you get the API Manager pack/what are the steps you followed to install the API Manager?

Comment: In addition to the above, can you share the startup logs of the WSO2 API Manager and the version?

Comment: The issue was solved by re-installing the database. Not sure why exactly. But thanks anyway.